# RecyclerView Images in wrong positions

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I'm using `Picasso` to display a grid of images but some images either appear on wrong positions or they appear two or more times.

This is the code for my `onBindViewHolder` method :

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

            PhotoViewHolder photoViewHolder = (PhotoViewHolder) viewHolder;
//                photoViewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);

            File imageDir = context.getDir(IMAGE_DIR, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            Post userPost = dataset.get(photoViewHolder.getAdapterPosition() - 1);

            if (networkUtils.isOnline()) {
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(userPost.getImage())
                        .placeholder(R.color.image_placeholder_color)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .fit()
                        .into(photoViewHolder.imageView);
            } else {

                String postId = String.valueOf(userPost.getPostId());

                if (imageDir.exists()) {
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(new File(imageDir + "/" +  postId + IMAGE_SUFFIX))
                            .placeholder(R.color.image_placeholder_color)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .fit()
                            .into(photoViewHolder.imageView);
                }

            }

            photoViewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(view ->
                    BusProvider.getInstance().post(new OpenUserProfilePhotoEvent(
                            userPost.getPostId(), Integer.valueOf(accountId))));

}
```

Using `setIsRecyclable(false)` helps solving this issue but it beats the purpose of `RecyclerView`.

Can you find what's wrong with my `onBindViewHolder`  ?

Comment: have u tried with  Post userPost = dataset.get(position); instead of  Post userPost = dataset.get(photoViewHolder.getAdapterPosition() - 1);

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: you remove the online check and do something similar  if (!img_url.equals("")){
    Picasso.with(context).load(img_url).into(holder.mImageView);
  } else {
    //todo - implement a default image in case img_url is indeed empty
    Picasso.with(context).load(defaultImage).into(holder.mImageView);
  } There is no need to check whether online on view holder.

Answer (score 0):

Use dataset.get(position) instead of dataset.get(photoViewHolder.getAdapterPosition() - 1).